# ubuntu 12.04 skype messages don't deliver

Tags: 12.04, skype

I've downloaded Skype from the official website, and opened it with Ubuntu-Software-Center, but later I tried to send messages but it doesn't deliver
any suggestions!

Comment: Ubuntu-Software-Center??

Comment: it's just like an ordinary (.deb) package to be installed.. yes

Answer (score 0):

Installing .deb file manually on ubuntu -

```
mkdir xxx
cd xxx
```

Now move your .deb file in /home/xxx/ and use the following -

to know the name of package_name.deb

```
ls
```

then

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

If you get any broken package error use -

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: it's not about the installation, unfortunately.. I think it's something about the configuration or something like that

Comment: have you installed it in this way after downloading it??

Comment: i tried the both ways